# Bash Arithmetic in Array index not working

Tags: arrays, bash

I have a bash script wherein I need to check an array based on a condition and if it matches I need to print the lines after that particular match. My code is below:`echo ${myArray[(($k+1))]}` doesn't work .

```
i=0;
for j in `cat sdp_aDT_dhk1smc3_Periodic_20140711.log` 
do
    array[$i]=$j; 

    i=$(($i+1)); 

done 
k=0;

for k in myArray;
    do
          if   myArray[$k]="MEMORY" ;  then

             echo ${myArray[(($k+1))]}
          fi

 done
```

Comment: You are missing `$` before `(($k+1))`.

Comment: Is that really your true code? at least myArray should be $myArray

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to print the lines that match with your particular condition, please try

```
myArray=`cat sdp_aDT_dhk1smc3_Periodic_20140711.log`
for k in $myArray;
do
    if [ "$k" = "MEMORY" ]
    then
        echo "$k"
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read that file contents into an array plain and simple with:

```
array=($(cat fileName))
```

No loop necessary for that.

Now, to your original question:  You seem to mix up `array` and `myArray`, or are they two different things?  Let's assume they are meant to be the same; so then I think you want to output the items directly *after* the items `MEMORY` (that's what your code looks like).  You can do that like this:

```
flag=false
for k in "${array[@]}"
do
    $flag && echo "$k"
    if [ "$k" = "MEMORY" ]
    then
        flag=true
    else
        flag=false
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply:

```
#!/bin/bash
readarray -t myArray < sdp_aDT_dhk1smc3_Periodic_20140711.log
for i in "${!myArray[@]}"; do
    if [[ ${myArray[i]} == 'MEMORY' ]]; then
        printf '%s\n' "${myArray[@]:i + 1}"
        break
    fi
done
```

- `readarray` converts lines from input to array
- `${!myArray[@]}` populates the indices, not the elements themselves
- `printf '%s\n'` prints every argument as a single line (creates multiple lines).
- `"${myArray[@]:i + 1}"` represents all elements after the matched element and expands to multiple arguments.

Refer to the [Bash Reference Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html) for everything.